# Diagonal square spiral pattern in Vyxal

Tags: strings, ascii-art, vyxal

I wrote this code as a reference implementation for [this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18300/100664). How can I make it more readable and/or efficient?

The goal is to take an integer and create patterns like the following:

```
/\
\/

/\
\/\
 \/

 /\
/\/\
\ \/
 \/

 /\
/  \
\  /\
 \/\/\
  \ \/
   \/
```

For n=1,2,3,4 respectively.

Code:

```
(
  n‹[
    n 4 % 2 = [
      4 n 4 ḭ e : →x ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ḂRJ ←x ( ¤ p ) $ ←x ( ¤ J) $ +
    | n 4 % 3 = [
      4 n 4 ḭ e : £ ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ¥ ɾ v\\ ¥ ꘍ v∞ Ȯ ṘRJJ ¥  ( ¤ p ) $ ¥ ( ¤ J) +
    | n 4 % 0 = [
      4 n 4 ḭ e ½ : →x ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ḂRJ ←x ( ¤ J ) $ ←x ( ¤ p) +
    |
      4 n 4 ḭ e ½ : £ ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ¥ ɾ v\\ ¥ ꘍ v∞ Ȯ ṘRJJ ¥  ( ¤ J ) $ ¥ ( ¤ p) $ +
    ]]] ƛ‛// \/ V `\\` \\ V;
  |
    k/Ḃ"
  ]
)
? ∷ [
 øĊ⁋
| ? ½ E : ½ ʁ Ṙ $ ʁ J $ ꘍ ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

A few high-level comments:

```
( # input times
  n‹[ # If n isn't the base case 1:
    n 4 % 2 = [ If n % 4 is 2, 3, 0, or 1, append the appropriate square / rectangle in the appropriate direction
      4 n 4 ḭ e : →x ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ḂRJ ←x ( ¤ p ) $ ←x ( ¤ J) $ +
    | n 4 % 3 = [
      4 n 4 ḭ e : £ ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ¥ ɾ v\\ ¥ ꘍ v∞ Ȯ ṘRJJ ¥  ( ¤ p ) $ ¥ ( ¤ J) +
    | n 4 % 0 = [
      4 n 4 ḭ e ½ : →x ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ḂRJ ←x ( ¤ J ) $ ←x ( ¤ p) +
    |
      4 n 4 ḭ e ½ : £ ƛ \/ $ ‹꘍; ⁋ øṀ ↵ ¥ ɾ v\\ ¥ ꘍ v∞ Ȯ ṘRJJ ¥  ( ¤ J ) $ ¥ ( ¤ p) $ +
    ]]] ƛ‛// \/ V `\\` \\ V; # Replace double slashes of either kind with slashes
  | # If n is the base case 1
    k/Ḃ" # Return `/\`, `\/`
  ]
)
? ∷ [ # If the input is odd
 øĊ⁋ # Center and join on newlines
| ? ½ E : ½ ʁ Ṙ $ ʁ J $ ꘍ ⁋ # Else prepend the appropriate padding
```

This keeps an array of rows on the stack, building it up iteration by iteration,by building the new squares/rectangle, then adding vertical padding to both and (vectorised) concatenating them and removing double-up slashes. Padding with spaces is not added until the end, to make it simpler to add new squares/rectangles.

For example, for n=2:

```
Base case: `/\`,`\/`
Iteration 2 shape: `\/`, `/\`
Padding added to both: [`/\`,`\/`, ``], [``,`/\`,`\/`]
Concatenated: `/\`,`\//\`,`\/`
Double slashes cleaned up: `/\`, `\/\`, `\/`
Padding added:
/\
\/\
 \/
```